# binary to decimal converter (including negative)

Tags: python, binary, decimal, converters

I need to convert from binary values such as '1010' to decimal values. this needs to include negative binary.

```
def BinaryToDecimal (n):

    n1 = n
    decimal = 0
    i = 0
    n = 0
    while(n != 0):
      dec = n % 10
      decimal = decimal + dec * pow(2, i)
      n = n//10
      i += 1
    print(decimal)
```

This is what i have so far, but it doesn't work. I'm not sure what else to do. Please help! I am not allowed to use any fancy python libraries, I am supposed to write the code manually.

Comment: You set n = 0 and then immediately test whether n != 0 in the while loop. change this and evaluate

Comment: Are you passing the binary number as a string or int? I'm not aware if the modulus operator is defined on strings.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
def BinaryToDecimal(n):
    n = str(n)
    print(int(n,2))
```

## Python shell output

Binary to decimal:

```
>>> bin_str = '11111111'
>>> int(bin_str,2)
255
```

Decimals to binary:

```
>>> decimal = 255
>>> "{:b}".format(decimal)
'11111111'
```